# Option to save output printed on screen as a text file (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Either I'm not using the right search string or this is buried deep within the interwebs. I know we aren't supposed to ask for homework answers, but I don't want the code answer, I want to know where to find it, cause my GoogleFu is busted.

Assignment is to create a program that will roll two 6-sided dice `n` times, with `n` being user-defined, between 1 and 9.  The program then displays the results, with `"Snake Eyes!"` if the roll is 1-1, and `"Boxcar!"` if the roll is 6-6. It also has to handle `ValueErrors` (like if someone puts "three" instead of "3") and return a message if the user chooses a number that isn't an integer 1-9.

Cool, I got all that.  But he also wants it to ask the user if they want to save the output to a text file.  Um.  Yeah, double-checked the book, and my notes, and he hasn't mentioned that **AT ALL**.  So now I'm stuck.  Can someone point me in the right direction, or tell me what specifically to search to find help?

Thanks!

Comment: `print()` takes an argument `file` which describe the file to output to. By default this is `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to store your final output to a text file.

```
def print_text(your_result):    
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(your_result)

# Take users input
user_input = input("Do you want to save results? Yes or No")

if(user_input == "Yes"):
    print_text(your_result)
```

I hope  this helps

Comment: But how do I give them the option?  It can't just write straight to it, they have to want a file saved.  I can import a file and append it, just don't know how to get the option in there.

Comment: Apparently I don't have my code set up properly, because I have no idea what I'm supposed to put in the place of "your_result".  And it won't let me put the code in here, because it's too long.  I'm so friggin frustrated with this.  I'm not a coder, I'm studying MIS lol.

Comment: Then God bless you. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Check out the input function:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input

It will allow you to request input from a user and store it in a variable.

Comment: I know how to ask them if they want it saved, but I have no idea how to actually have it save what it put on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not pretty, but I came up with this:

```
def print_text():
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(dice))

loop = True
import random
min = 1
max = 6
dice = []
while loop is True:
    try:
        rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?  Enter a whole number between 1 and 9: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid option, please try again.")
    else:
        if 1 <= rolls <= 9:
            n = 0
            while n < rolls:
                n = n + 1
                print("Rolling the dice ...")
                print("The values are:")
                dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
                dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
                dice.append(dice1)
                dice.append(dice2)
                print(dice1, dice2)
                diceTotal = dice1 + dice2
                if diceTotal == 2:
                    print("Snake Eyes!")
                elif diceTotal == 12:
                    print("Boxcar!")
        else: print("Invalid option, please try again.")

    saveTxt = input("Would you like to save as a text file?  Y or N: ")
    if saveTxt == "Y" or saveTxt == "y":
        print_text()
        break
```